# Merging file chunks PHP

Tags: php

I have implemented a library (Dropzone.js) to upload large files to my server from my application (divided into pieces of 5 Mb) and works perfectly.

If I wanted to download the file from the server. how to join the pieces with PHP?

[image]

**(Not always the file uploaded is a .rar, it can be any type of file)**

I trying something like this.

```html
<?php

$target_path = 'upload/';
$directory = opendir($target_path); //get all files in the path
$files = array() ;
$c =0;
while ($archivo = readdir($directory)) //
{
    if (is_dir($archivo))//check whether or not it is a directory
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $files= $target_path.$archivo;
        $c++;
    }
}

$final_file_path =$target_path;
$catCmd = "cat " . implode(" ", $files) . " > " . $final_file_path;
exec($catCmd);
?>
```

Comment: `$files= $target_path.$archivo;` should be `$files[] = $target_path.$archivo;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is that you need to build an array but you overwrite `$files` each iteration, so:

```
$files[] = $target_path.$archivo;
```

However, you can make it much shorter:

```
$target_path = 'upload';
$files = array_filter(glob("$target_path/*"), 'is_file');
$catCmd = "cat " . implode(" ", $files) . " > $target_path/NEW";
exec($catCmd);
```

- `glob` for all files in the directory
- filter on only the entries that `is_file`
- `implode` and execute as you were
- specify a name for the new file, I used `NEW`

Comment: thanks for answering
I'm testing with the shorter code
but, e throws the following error

|||||||||||||||||||||||||--------------------- error ----------------------------||||||||||
Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in  |||||||||||||||||||||||||--------------------- error ----------------------------||||||||||   Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: I edited it quickly but evidently not quickly enough, it should be `array_filter`.